# Deep cloning an object with Automapper, can't exclude Id property on objects in a List<abstractBaseClass> property

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Question : IQuestion
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Some other base properties here
}

public class TextQuestion : Question
{
  // Some class-specific properties here
}
```

And a class like this:

```
public class SomeCompositeClass
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Some properties go here ...

  public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a deep clone of the `SomeCompositeClass`, using Automapper (please don't suggest `ICloneable`), but without all the IDs, because I will be inserting it in the database, which I access with EntityFramework, repository pattern.

Naturally, I create a mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeCompositeClass, SomeCompositeClass>().ForMember(rec => rec.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

and this works out great for the `SomeCompositeClass`.

**But I have a problem doing the same thing for the Questions property! The problem comes from the base class in the List being `abstract`, not because the list itself is `virtual`, I have already ruled this out.**

If I create a `Mapper.CreateMap<Question, Question>()` or `Mapper.CreateMap<IQuestion, IQuestion>()` mapping, the code throws an exception at runtime, complaining that it cannot create an instance of an abstract (`Question`) object.

I have tried `Mapper.CreateMap<List<Question>, List<Question>>()`, but this just gives me an empty `Questions` list at runtime.

I have tried creating question-specific mappings (`TextQuestion` to `TextQuestion`), but they don't kick in, because the objects in the `Questions` property are wrapped in EF's `DynamicProxy` classes.

What can I do, to exclude the Id from the inheritors of my abstract base `Question` class, during the Mapper.Map(...)?

Comment: OK, I've done it. And now I have `Mapper.CreateMap<Question, Question>().ForMember(rec => rec.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())`, however, this messes up my instances of the classes. They arrive 'boxed' in that list, and during the Mapping with that map, they don't get unboxed - hence, they remain the basic Question type. Any idea?

Comment: Somehow I need to tell Automapper, for IQuestion to ignore certain properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

First, I updated to Automapper 4.1.1. Then:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Question, Question>()
                .Include<TextBoxQuestion, TextBoxQuestion>()
                    // Supposedly inheritance mapping?
                    .ForMember(rec => rec.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<TextBoxQuestion, TextBoxQuestion>()
                // But either I don't understand inheritance mapping or it doesn't work, soI have to do that too
                .ForMember(rec => rec.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<SomeCompositeClass, SomeCompositeClass>()
                .ForMember(rec => rec.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
        }

        ...
        Mapper.Map(source, destination);
```

and it works...

So I think what I was mostly missing was the `.Include` part, which tells Automapper to look for the most derived class.